# How do I fix the 'Specified class name 'WpfSample.MainWindow' doesn't match actual root instance type 'System.Windows.Window' error?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

So I am trying to use a custom wpf control on a winforms using:

```
var f = new FileStream (@"C:\sample.xaml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
var element = XamlReader.Load(f);

f.Close();

var elementHost = new ElementHost();
elementHost.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;   
elementHost.Child = element;
this.Controls.Add(elementHost);
```

I am not experienced in WPF so I don't know how to fix this error.

EDIT:

So this is the xaml file:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfSample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:r="http://schemas.aspitalia.com/Ricciolo/Controls" 
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>


            <XmlDataProvider x:Key="data" Source="Data.xml">
            </XmlDataProvider>

            <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="dt" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=outline}">
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        </Grid.Resources>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <r:TreeListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource data},XPath=/opml/body/outline/outline}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource dt}">
            <r:TreeListView.Columns>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Title" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=@title}" Width="150" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Childs" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=@count}" Width="100" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Url" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=@xmlUrl}" Width="200" />
            </r:TreeListView.Columns>
        </r:TreeListView>


    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I also got this from a free custom treelistview control on the net, and included both the compiled control and the data.xml in the solution, this xaml uses.

EDIT2:

Code behind for MainWindow.xaml:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfSample
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow ( )
        {
            InitializeComponent ( );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is (probably) because of `sample.xaml` and the code behind. Could you please provide those two items?

Comment: Thanks, will post it in a moment, but the code behind is standard, i.e. I changed nothing.

Comment: What language is that ? That's clearly not C#, and it's not VB either...

Comment: Sorry I quickly patched up that code to show the intent, now fixed it.

Comment: Can you post the code behind of your xaml MainWindow file please?

Comment: OK I added it, just thought it wouldn't help since I didn't change it.

Answer (score 1):

OK.  I think the problem is coming from the fact that you are loading from a file, but the Window class that backs it (i.e. the code behind object) isn't being brought in with it.

You should either define the WPF control (not sure if a WPF Window should be used - maybe try UserControl instread?) in the same assembly as the WinForms app, or simply add a reference to the assembly that contains the WPF UserControl, and hook it up that way.

Either way, you should just be able to say

```
elementHost.Child = new WpfSample.MainWindow();
this.Controls.Add(elementHost);
```

Hope this gets you close.